# Difference between spacetime diffeomorphism and coordinate transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry

Usually, spacetime diffeomorphism could be understood as a positive version of coordinate transformation. While the coordinate transformation is a change of chart, a diffeomorphism is a map $f: U\rightarrow V$ (here we simply use $V=U$). So my question are they just a different view of the same thing, or there are some cases they are not totally equivalent? Which diffeomorphism correspond to the transformation between cartesian coordinates and polar coordinates?

Comment: In the context of GR, and almost all modern theories, they are the same: they lead to the same transformation rules. (Provided all the things we always usually assume to be true hold, e.g., overlapping coordinate charts, etc).